# Register DLL in GAC (CMD or PowerShell)

Tags: windows, powershell, dll, gac

I'm trying to register a `.DLL` in the `GAC`.
Currently I'm having trouble to prove it has been added to the assembly.

Using the command

> C:\Windows\System32>%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\gacutil.exe -i "path\to\my\file.dll"

The prompt tells me that the assembly has been added to the cache.

When checking with

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>gacutil.exe -l file.dll

It says that there are 0 elements in the assembly.

Via `Powershell` commands, I'm trying to add the `DLL` like this:

> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Add-Type -AssemblyName
>   "System.EnterpriseServices"
>
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $publish =
>   New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish
>
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $publish.GacInstall("file.dll")

What did I do wrong? How can I add the `.DLL` to the `GAC`? The best way (for me) would be doing that with `Powershell`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remember to run PowerShell as administrator or this won't work.

```
$dllpath = c:\path\yourdll.dll
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")            
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish            
$publish.GacInstall($dllpath)
```

You will likely need to restart whatever related service or program after this, for example:

```
if (Get-Service "YourService" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
        Stop-Service -Name 'YourService' 
        Start-Service -Name 'YourService' 

    }
```

Or just restart your computer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When trying the first command via Powershell, I get this message:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $dllpath = C:\temp\file.dll

Fehler beim Ausführen des Programms "file.dll": Der angegebenen Datei ist keine Anwendung zugeordnetIn Zeile:1
Zeichen:12
+ $dllpath = C:\temp\file.dll
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ $dllpath = C:\temp\file.dll
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

I get an error... but why?

Comment: @TimD. Could you translate the errors to English please?

Comment: It says **"error when executing the program file.dll" The file is not assinged to an application. In line: 1 character: 12."** The rest is in english as you can see.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it with these Powershell lines:

```js
Set-location "C:\Temp"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish
$publish.GacInstall("C:\Temp\file.dll")
```

After restarting the PC/Server, the dll is registered in the GAC. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `*.bat` to install or update `DLL` to `GAC` using `GacUtil.exe` within the `visual studio developer command prompt`

```
@ECHO OFF
cls
ECHO ------: GAC UPDATER :-----
ECHO -                        -
ECHO  - Updating  %1
gacutil /if %1
```

Save this as `install.bat` and call it with a parameter like `install abcd.dll` the `%1` will receive the parameter as text and will serve Gacutil as `gacutil /if abcd.dll`, the `/if` here forces to install the dll thus updating it in case it already available.

In absence of the `GacUtil.exe` you can use the `powershell` script below

```
Set-location (Get-Location).Path
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish
$publish.GacInstall((Get-Location).Path + "\YourFile.dll")
```

This `powershell` script gets the current location of itself and assumes the `YourFile.dll` to be next to it, in case the `dll` is in some remote location update the script to replace `$publish.GacInstall((Get-Location).Path + "\YourFile.dll")` with `$publish.GacInstall("path to \YourFile.dll")`

Save the script as `install.ps1`remember to replace the `YourFile.dll` with your `dll` name and place it next to the the script file then execute the script

Answer (score 0):

how to install dll in gac using powershell on Azure , using azure storage , i make 2 fils renci_dll.ps1 (this is my powershell file) and main.cmd ti call my powershell file and this is the code of my powershell file that does not works , because i have an error when i restart IR SSIS and I execute the deployed package on server Azure

Note that : in desktop i install the dll easly and packages runs successfully , the problem in cloud
**renci_dll.ps1 :**

Set-location (Get-Location).Path
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish
$publish.GacInstall((Get-Location).Path + "\Renci.SshNet.dll")  [image]

Answer (score -1):

Check the filename without the extension (.dll)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>gacutil.exe -l file